# Where are the endpoints defined here?

Tags: c#, wcf, binding

I'm having trouble with a WCF service. I'm not an expert in this area so I decided to create a new project and just look at what it started me out with. It starts out with a sample Service1.svc file and when I hit F5 on it then it brings up the WCF Test Client. So far so good... until I look to see how the endpoints/bindings/whatever are defined.

But I see absolutely nothing in the webconfig that says anything about Service1. And if I make a copy of this file but change the name of the class in the new file to Service2 and select it before hitting F5 then it complains at me and the WCF Test Client doesn't see anything.

Here is the webconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So if there's nothing in the webconfig about Service1 then how does the WCF Test Client know anything about it when I bring it up? I'm definitely confused here... seems like there should be some more stuff in the webconfig.

Comment: See the <system.serviceModel> tag! That's where they should be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please [refer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734786%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this will help you for How to create service endpoints.

**" Endpoint is a portal for communicating with the world.
All the WCF communications are take place through end point. End point consists of three components.**"
Address , Binding and Contract

**EDIT**

just try [simplified configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee530014.aspx). If you create project in .NET 4.0 you will get this simplified mode.

Comment: Sorry Imran, but I wasn't asking how to define an endpoint. I was asking how the WCF test client can see Service1 and let me invoke it successfully when there are no endpoints defined for it in the webconfig file.

Answer (score 0):

An endpoint is made up a few pieces of information as [explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733107%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The first two, address and binding inferred by the web request to `http://host:port/Service1.svc` and the contract is defined by `IService1.cs` which should contain an interface which describes the methods offered by your service. The implementation of your service is in `Service1.svc.cs`.

The bits in web.config are just specifying a few defaults for all behaviors used by all services. A behavior is a way of describing details of the service offering, like how it exposes metadata, handles security, etc. Most of this defaults decently though.

You might find it helpful to look at what's actually in `Service1.svc` (right-click and select View Markup) as well.

Answer (score 0):

you have define basic ABC of WCF service however I am sharing sample web.config file of my WCF service. Please update your web.config file and I sure that your service will work

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"/>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="DataService.DataService">
    <endpoint address="web" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="DataService.IDataService"/>
     <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding" contract="DataService.IDataService"  />
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="DataService.IDataService"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"  faultExceptionEnabled="True" defaultBodyStyle="Bare" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="True"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" allowCookies="true">
      <security mode="None"></security>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
 <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding" allowCookies="true">
      <security mode="None"></security>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Rachit, the service works already... I'm just trying to understand 'why' it works because it seems like there is information missing from the webconfig.